# FreeIPA for Zabbix authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, zabbix, freeipa

[FreeIPA config for Zabbix auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek6z1.png)

I want to use FreeIPA server for authentication in Zabbix, but I don't understand what do I need to write in the fields of the server's configuration on the image. Test login is successful but when I enable LDAP authentication I have an error like wrong password or login or user is being temporarily blocked. I can log in to FreeIPA's accounts on client's computers.

I've tried to enable JIT provisioning, but it seems like it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Zabbix LDAP server parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgCBG.png)

Worked for me. I needed to create a user with the same username as in FreeIPA without password and then use the parameters on the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm the future, if you can avoid posting screenshots of values and instead include them directly in your answer, that is generally better for visibility.

But otherwise great effort! Thank you!

Comment: That doesn't sound right. If authentication fails, "make it passwordless" is not the right approach, even if it happens to work. Now you have a passwordless IPA account that can list all your user information...

Answer (score 0):

I've just set up Zabbix 7.0.0alpha9 (current as of 2024-01-27), and just got LDAP working!

On the Users>Authentication>Authentication page:

- Default authentication: LDAP
- Deprovisioned users group: "disabled"

On the Users>Authentication>LDAP settings page:

- Enable LDAP authentication: yes
- Enable JIT provisioning: yes
- One server listed: server1

Click on server1, see these settings:

- Name: server1 (cosmetic name)
- Host: ip or hostname of your ldap server
- Port: 389 (ldap) or 636 (ldaps)
- Base DN: cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
- Search attribute: uid
- Bind DN: uid=zabbix-service,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com

  - This is the Distinguished Name (DN) of a no-privilege account created just for zabbix to do authentication
- Bind password:
- Configure JIT provisioning: yes
- Group configuration: memberOf
- Group name attribute: cn
- User group membership attribute: memberOf

  - :warning: THIS field had a faint 'memberOf' in it, but you must type it yourself or it won't work!!!
- User name attribute: givenName
- User last name attribute: sn

Click on 'Add' under 'User group mapping'

- LDAP group pattern: the name of an LDAP group ("*" allowed)
- User groups: the name(s) of the Zabbix group(s) to add the users to
- User role: pick the role to assign: Admin/Guest/Super admin/User/etc
  Click on 'Add' under 'Media type mapping'
- Name: the name of an LDAP attribute, like 'mail'
- Media type: which media type (e.g. "Email (HTML)")
- Attribute: The zabbix attribute to map into, like 'mail'

The equivalent ldapsearch commands (reconstructed from the dirsrv access log on the ldap server) are:

```
# See if the user exists:
ldapsearch -LL \
 -H ldap://1.2.3.4 \
 -D 'uid=zabbix-service,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com' \
 -w "$ZABBIX_PW" \
 -b "cn=accounts,dc=netskrt,dc=io" \
  "(uid=$USERNAME)" \
  distinguishedName

# Get the user details:
ldapsearch -LL \
 -H ldap://1.2.3.4 \
 -D 'uid=zabbix-service,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com' \
 -w "$ZABBIX_PW" \
 -b "cn=accounts,dc=netskrt,dc=io" \
  "(uid=$USERNAME)" \
  mail uid givenName sn

# Check the username+password (binding, sort of):
ldapsearch -LL \
 -H ldap://1.2.3.4 \
 -D 'uid=$USERNAME,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com' \
 -w "$LOGIN_PW" \
 -b "cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=netskrt,dc=io" \
  "(uid=$USERNAME)"

# Get the group memberships (if JIT is set up right!):
ldapsearch -LL \
 -H ldap://1.2.3.4 \
 -D 'uid=$USERNAME,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com' \
 -w "$LOGIN_PW" \
 -b "cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=netskrt,dc=io" \
  "(uid=$USERNAME)" \
  mail uid memberOf givenName sn
```

Good luck!